# Number of ways to place integers 1-64 in arithmetic progression in one row and column on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics

Integers $\{1,2,...,64\}$ are placed on a $8\times8$ chessboard. How many ways are there to place them such that all numbers in the 1st row and column are in arithmetic progression?

This is what I tried:
Let the numbers in the first row be $\{a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_8\}$ and first column be $\{a_1,b_1, \ldots ,h_1\}$.
Common difference of first row is $d$ and of first column is $D$.

I set $\gcd(d,D)=1$.
I tried listing all possible $(a1,d,D)$ but it was a lengthy method.

Can someone suggest any other way of solving this?

Comment: I finally guess it is probably arithmetic-progression

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I will keep this in mind the next time.

Comment: There are hundreds of cases with $d_1 < 0, d_2 > 0$. Any $d_1 < 0, d_2 > 0 : \lvert d_1 \rvert + \lvert d_2 \rvert \le 9$ will work for some range of values (though if the sum is $9$, there are only two possibilities, as $1+(9 \times 7) = 64$.) Those should be readily calculable without enumerating them. Finding $a_1, d_1, d_2 > 0$ will be the tough part; I'm not sure exactly how to go about it but I'm sure we can do better than a computer program.

Comment: @EricSnyder It's not that tough. For that case of $d_1 < 0 < d_2$, we have $ 1 \leq a_1 + 7 d_1 \leq a_1 + 7 d_2 \leq 64$ and so can count the number of solutions for each $d_1, d_2$ pair. In fact, it's a constant for $|d_1| + |d_2|$, so we just have 9 cases.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sure, but the cases for $0 < d_1 \le d_2$ are a little tougher. Though I *think* there are very few of them.

Comment: @CalvinLin Also, there are more than nine cases... The number of solutions for any $|d_1|+|d_2|$ may be constant, but there are, for instance, $5$ cases with $|d_1|+|d_2|=6$, etc.

Comment: (I agree with you but you misunderstand me.) To clarify, for each of the 9 values of $ C = |d_1| + |d_2|$ (of which each of these cases has $C-1$ sub-cases for pairs of $(d_1, d_2)$), the number of solutions is ... (a simple function of $C$).

Comment: @CalvinLin Ah yes, we definitely agree. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Some incorrect summation has been repaired.
**Edit 2**: You forget arithmetic when you learn higher math. After going over the summations a dozen times I'm still getting a discrepancy. Edits below.

We have two cases: either both differences are positive or not. We can rewrite the sequences in both cases to our advantage. Instead of considering just whether the difference or positive or negative, let's separate into two cases:

1. The last term of one (ascending) sequence is the first term of the other $(d_1 < 0 < d_2)$ (**Easy**)
2. The first terms of the (ascending) sequences are the same $(d_1, d_2 > 0)$ (**Hard**)

We'll restate the sequence for each case In addition, we will take the numbers as being on chessboard squares $\text{h1, g1,} \cdots \text{b1, } \color{#00FF00}{\text{a1}} \text{, a2, a3,} \cdots \text{a7, a8}$, where the common element of the two sequences in on a1 and highlighted in green. (We can safely pick the bottom rank and then rotate $90$º CCW.)

**Easy Cases**:

First, we take the *inverse* of $d_1$ to make it positive, and redefine our two sequences as:

$$(a, a+d_1, a+2d_1, a+3d_1, a+4d_1, a+5d_1, a+6d_1, \color{#00FF00}{a+7d_1 = b}) \\ (\color{#00FF00}{a+7d_1=b}, b+d_2, b+2d_2,b+3d_2, b+4d_2, b+5d_2, b+6d_2, b+7d_2)$$

Highlighted in green is the common element of the two sequences.  Doing this now means the "easy" cases have $d_1, d_2 > 0$, rather than dealing with one negative.

We have $a \ge 1$, and $a+7d_1+7d_2 \le 64$. Hence $d_1 + d_2 \le (64-1)/7 = 9$. For a given case, we have $64 - 7(d_1+d_2)$ solutions available. (Consider the shortest case, $d_1=d_2=1$, for which the smallest solution is $(1, 2, \cdots 7, \color{#00FF00}{8}, 9, \cdots 14, 15)$. It can end with any number between $15$ and $64$, giving $64-14=50$ separate solutions.) Now we need to sum those up. There will *appear* to be some duplications, but if $d_1 \ne d_2$, then those are two different solutions (check for yourself). In addition, at the end we must multiply everything by $2$, as each solution's reflection is also a solution. Our sum, then, is:

$$2 \sum_{d_i, d_2}^{d_1+d_2 \le 9} 64 - 7(d_1+d_2) = 3584 - 14\sum_{d_i, d_2}^{d_1+d_2 \le 9} (d_1+d_2)$$

Here $3584 = 2 \cdot 64 \cdot 28$, as there are $28$ cases. It's clear there is just one case where $d_1+d_2=2$, $2$ where that sum is $3$, and so on up to $8$ cases with a sum of $9$. That means we can rewrite as:

$$3584 - 14\sum_{n=1}^{7} n(n+1) = 3584 - 14 \cdot 168 = 1232$$

So, $1232$ solutions for the easy cases.

But! I have a discrepancy of $16$ calculating this two different ways. So... that means it might be $1248$.

**Hard Cases**:

These are trickier, though we keep both differences as positive. First, let's rewrite our sequences again:

$$(a+7d_1, a+6d_1, a+5d_1, a+4d_1, a+3d_1, a+2d_1, a+d_1, \color{#00FF00}{a}) \\
(\color{#00FF00}{a}, a+d_2, a+2d_2, a+3d_2, a+4d_2, a+5d_2, a+6d_2, a+7d_2)$$

First, the obvious sequential arrangement on the board gives us the solution $(8, 7, \cdots 2, \color{#00FF00}{1}, 9, 17, \cdots 49, 55)$. And there are $16$ such solutions (including the reverses), up to $(15, 14, \cdots 9, \color{#00FF00}{8}, 16, 24, \cdots 56, 64)$. We multiply by $2$ *again* because we could have both $d_1, d_2 < 0$, that is, the second AP originates from the *largest* number in the first. That's $32$ total solutions. What about other possibilities?

Let's rewrite that last question as:

*How do we determine whether two arithmetic progressions have a number in common?*

More specifically, do they have a common element in the first eight terms?  So knowing that, when is there a common value (other than $a$) between the two sequences given above? Assume $d_1=1$. Then $a+d_2$ cannot be any of $a+d_1, a+2d_1, \cdots a+7d_1$. But that means our only choice is $d_2=8$ or $d_2=9$. Any other choice of $d_2$ will clash, because $a+d_1d_2$ will appear in both sequences! $d_2=8$ is the simple case just shown. We'll deal with $d_1=9$ in a moment.

Building from this clashing idea: we must avoid any case in which $a+d_1d_2$ accidentally appears in both sequences. That means we must avoid $1 \le d_1, d_2 \le 7$. That means we can *only* use sequences where either $d_1$ or $d_2$ is equal to $8$ or $9$.

OK, how to count those? Well, there's exactly one arithmetic progression with $d_1=9$ that we can use, and that's $(1, 10, 19, \cdots 55, 64)$. We can tack on any $d_2$ we want *except# for $d_2=3, 6$, thanks to that common divisor issue. That's $6$ solutions, $\times 2$ by reflection, and $\times 2$ because our second AP can originate from either $1$ or $64$ (decreasing in the latter case), for $24$ total.

For $d_1=8$, we have more possibilities. We can only have $d_2=1,3,5,7,9$ thanks to divisibility by even numbers, though wait, we already counted the $8,9$ pair and its reflections above. The AP with $d_1=8$ can have $8$ different starting points. We double twice as above, for $4 \cdot 4 \cdot 8 = 128$ different solutions. Note this includes the $32$ solutions from our sample case.

That gives a total of $152$ solutions for the hard cases.

---

Altogher, that's $1232 + 152 = \mathbf{1384}$ unique solutions. Or possibly $1400$ if my math is right/wrong.

Comment: I disagree with "In addition, at the end we must multiply everything by 2". While it is true that the reflection is also a solution, you've already accounted for it. EG The $(-1, 2)$ and $(-2, 1)$ have been counted separately, so why are you doubling? The $(-1, 1,  a = 20)$ and $(-1, 1, a = 44)$ are likewise counted separately.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your hard case (Thanks for pointing out that not all $d_1, d_2$ pairs could work due to the overlap. The other solution writer missed that And yes, that makes this the hard case). $\quad$ 1/ We could have $(1, 9)$, but you only allow $ |d_1 | + |d_2| \leq 8 < 9$. 2/ We could have $(3, 8)$, but you only allow for $(1, 8)$.

Comment: Because I've treated all the differences as positive (in the easy cases), none of the decreasing series are represented. For instance, for the $(-1, 2)$ and $(-2,1)$ cases, setting $a=1$ (in my reformulation) give $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,[8],10,12,14,16,18,20,22)$ and $(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,[15],16,17,18,19,20,21,22)$ respectively. Then the doubling is for the descending sequence. Is that still unclear?

Comment: @CalvinLin OTOH, your second comment is totally valid; the $|d_1|+|d_2| \le 9$ doesn't apply here. Oops! Back to editing.

Comment: You're making my point. (I'm choosing to keep the negative sign in so that I can reduce cognitive overhead, bear with me). The $(-1, 2, a = 15)$ case and the reflection of $(-2, 1, a = 65-15 = 50)$ cases are the same $(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, [15], 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22)$, so we shouldn't count the reflection (even though yes it is a valid solution, it is not a distinct solution). I just didn't specify the value of $a$ but we were including all possible ones (Also, the substation should be $a \rightarrow 65 - a$, whereas I was incorrectly using $64 - a$)

Comment: @CalvinLin Wait, are you suggesting that $(1,2, \cdots 7,8,10, \cdots 20,22)$ is *not* distinct from $(22,20, \cdots 10,8,7 \cdots 2,1)$? They become distinct because of the 90° turn in the chessboard.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant $(-1, 2, b = 50 )$.  That gives us $(43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, [50], 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64)$. It's reflection is $(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, [15], 16, 17, 28, 19, 20, 21, 22)$, which is $(-2, 1, b = 15)$. Agree that this is distinct from $(-1, 2, b = 15$ or 7) $\quad$ Unless you sneaked in a $|d_1| \leq |d_2| $ condition somewhere?

Comment: OK, apologies for the many, many edits here. I should know better than to check my arithmetic only three times. And there's *still* a discrepancy of $16$ I can't find. Argh.

Comment: 1/ Oh, for the easy case, I get what you mean by "multiply by 2 because of reflection", you were doing $\pm (d_1, d_2)$, whereas I thought you were reflecting with $a_{ij}^* = 65 -a_{ij}$. I agree with you for now (but didn't check calculations) thought, see point 4 below .... $\quad$  2/ For the hard case, we could have $d_1 = 2, d_2 = 4$ not coprime case, like with  $(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15)$ paired with $(15, 19, 23, ... )$. $\quad$ 3/ For the hard case, you got the $(d_1, d_2)$, but haven't conditioned on $a$ as yet. EG For $d_1 = 9$, you mentioned "multiply by 2 because a = 1 or 64".

Comment: 4/ HOWEVER, building off point 2, the biggest issue that we both missed, is assuming that the term that is shared must be at the start and end of the sequence. That need not be the case, like with $(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, \color{red}{13}, 15)$ pairing with $(10, \color{red}{13}, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31)$,

Comment: Since the question specifies the **first** row and column, the shared term must be at the ends.

Comment: Depends on how you interpret "numbers are in arithmetic progression". does the order of the numbers in that row/column matter? If yes, then we're fine after making the above tweaks. If no, then my point stands and this gets more complicated.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I was assuming the question was asking for a continuous progression; asking otherwise seems unlikely to me. @Larissa, can you clarify whether the question wants the numbers to be in progression *as ordered on the board*, or just in progression as a set?